# Java or R2E regex to match series of numbers starting with %

Tags: java, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to match the following number series using java or R2E regex for AWS Cloudwatch logs.

The number series is following.
961540,%20961557,%20961565,%20961573,%20961581,%20961599

I have so far tried the following with no luck,
[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*,?%)

NOTE - The %20 at the beginning is a URL Encoded space

Comment: Note: `URLDecoder` can be used to decode such strings (e.g. put spaces in place of `%20`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a repeating pattern starting witj the comma and %

```
[0-9]+(?:,%20[0-9]+)*
```

https://regex101.com/r/PlEScm/1

Or if the %20 is already decoded to a space

```
[0-9]+(?:, [0-9]+)
```